# Making a PHP IF Statement to determine if there's any Results from a MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where drinks are sorted by brand and by 'product description' or 'grade'. When visiting a page for a particular drink, amongst other menus one of the menus shows the product description of the current drink (and if clicked on goes to a page showing other drinks from different brands with the same product description) and on hover over shows drinks from the *same* brand with a *different* product description (the hover effects are done with simple CSS).

This all works fine - however some brands only have a single product, meaning that the menu appears but with zero height (except for the border) and no data in it, which doesn't look good. So what I want is an IF statement that'll detect whether there are any results from the MySQL query and use different CSS depending on the result - however I just can't seem to find a way that works.

($Brand and $ProductDescription are defined earlier, and refer to the current drink)

```
<?php
$sql = "

SELECT DISTINCT 
    ProductDescription 
FROM 
    WebDatabaseText 
WHERE 
    Brand='$Brand' AND 
    ProductDescription<>'$ProductDescription' AND 
    Hide=0 AND  
    Language='$Language' AND  
    Website='$Website' AND  
    ProductDescription <> '(brand notes)' 
ORDER BY 
    ProductDescription

";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

If there's at least one result:

```
echo "<ul id='nav' class='drop'>
        <li><a href='/english/grades/?Grade=". $ProductDescription . "'>" . $ProductDescription . "</a>      ";


    echo    "  <ul>";


    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<li><a href='/english/products/?Brand=" . $Brand . "&ProductDescription=". $row["ProductDescription"] . "'>" . $row["ProductDescription"] . "</a>  </li>";
        }


    echo "  </ul>    </li>    ";

    echo    "  </ul>";
```

If there's nothing:

```
echo "<ul id='nav' class='drop'>
        <a href='/english/grades/?Grade=". $ProductDescription . "'>" . $ProductDescription . "</a> </ul>

?>
```

Comment: Just use `mysqli_num_rows()` to see how many results you got. (It looks like you're using mysqli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of found records is in `mysqli_num_rows` function.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while (...) {
        ...
    }
} else {
    echo 'Nothing found';
}
```

Comment: That just seems to break the code completely (doesn't show anything)

Comment: @MattBowyer: If you see blank page, you have there syntax error. This code is okay, problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Edit - I've realised why none of my previous attempts were working, too many brackets! (I'd put an extra one in by accident!)

Comment: @MattBowyer: so, it's working now? I tried to show you where the `while` loop will be. It's normal and easy condition.

Comment: Yes it is working - I was just being an idiot! Your solution worked fine thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   //your while loop here
} else {
    //do something
}
```